# React native firebase chat app for client and user

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have two different react native apps with two separate firebase android apps. I want to create chat logic between both the apps using firebase messaging and firestore db so that the client app can send messages to user app and vice-versa.

This is client app code but is useful for chatting with clients only not users.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(item.userName)
        .get()
        .then(documentSnapshot => {
            console.log('User exist: ', documentSnapshot.exists);

            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                // console.log('User data: ', documentSnapshot.data().message);
                setMessagesList(documentSnapshot.data().message);

                
                //This logic is for saving the recieved message to firestore but in the same app

                messaging().onMessage(remoteMessage => {
                    const prevMessages = documentSnapshot.data().message;
                    console.log("prev: ", prevMessages);
                    let date = Date();
                    let hour = (new Date(date)).getHours();
                    let minute = (new Date(date)).getMinutes();
                    let AmPm = hour >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                    let finalhour = hour >= 12 ? (hour - 12) : hour;
                    const newMessage = {
                        id: prevMessages.length + 1,
                        message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
                        time: `${finalhour}:${minute} ${AmPm}`,
                        isSender: false,
                        isSeen: false,
                    }
                    prevMessages.push(newMessage);
                    console.log("prev2: ", prevMessages);
                    setMessagesList(prevMessages);

                    firestore()
                        .collection('Users')
                        .doc(item.userName)
                        .set({
                            message: prevMessages
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log('User added!');
                            updateState({gotData: true});
                        });
                });
            }
        });

}, []);
```

The function to send messages :

```
function addMessage({ message }) {

    const oldMessages = messagesList;
    let date = Date();
    let hour = (new Date(date)).getHours();
    let minute = (new Date(date)).getMinutes();
    let AmPm = hour >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    let finalhour = hour >= 12 ? (hour - 12) : hour;

    const newMessage = {
        id: messagesList.length + 1,
        message: message,
        time: `${finalhour}:${minute} ${AmPm}`,
        isSender: true,
        isSeen: false,
    }

    oldMessages.push(newMessage);
    setMessagesList(oldMessages);

    // console.log("user : ", messagesList);

    firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(item.userName)
        .set({
            message: messagesList
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('User added!');
        });
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? Is there an error? If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I am sending these messages as a notification from one app to another. Is it possible to save my messages on the second app's firestore database directly from my first app? The above-given code works but there is a flaw. It only works when both apps are in open or in the background state. It stops working if one app is in quit state. All I want to ask that can I access my second app's firestore database in my first app. If yes, then how?